# Cannot change style of datetimepicker element

Tags: jquery, css, datetimepicker

---

I use very nice [jQuery datetimepicker plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) by XDSoft.

In options, I set method `onSelectDate`, which is triggered when user select date from *datepicker* and I want ask to the database, if there is some reserved times for that date and if so, remove that times from *timepicker*, so user cannot choose them.

I ran into problem with hidding reserved times. It seems, that changing style of containing element not working. I tried `addClass('hidden')`, `fadeOut()`, `hide()` even `css('color','red)` does not work. But, when I issue `console.log($(this).html())`, I see, that element is properly targeted.

Html element for picking times is dynamically added  by plugin and looks like this:

```
<div class="containing datetime picker elements">
  ...
    <div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="9" data-minute="30">09:30</div>
    <div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="10" data-minute="00">10:00</div>
  ...
</div>
```

My jQuery code for hide it:

```
onSelectDate: function() {

    var dennyTimes = [    //test array, instead database call
        0900,
        1100,
        1200,
        2100
        ];

    $('.xdsoft_time_box .xdsoft_time').each(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        var hour = that.data('hour');
        var time = hour * 100 + that.data('minute'); // time as integer

        that.show();            

        var i = dennyTimes.length;      
        while(i) {
        i--;
        //assume that times in dennyTimes are start time
        //of a reserved event and event is nearly one hour long,
        //so if it begins at 800, it ends nearly at 900
        if (time >= dennyTimes[i] && time < dennyTimes[i] + 100)
            that.hide();        
        }
    });
}
```

I thing this code should be allright. My guess is, that datetimepicker is dynamically created some wrong way, that prevents me from change style, but I have no clue. Do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find working solution.

Firstly, I moved all options into variable `var datetimepickerOptions`, then the plugin is initialized with

```
$('#datepicker_input').datetimepicker(datetimepickerOptions);
```

And in options I write `onSelectDate` function, that appends array of available times as native `allowTimes` property into `datetimepickerOptions` and then reinitialize datetimepicker plugin with extended options.

### EDIT: add complete code:

```
var datetimepickerOptions = {
    lang: 'cs',
    format: 'd. m. Y H:i',
    step: 30,
    minTime: '8:30',
    maxTime: '17:30',
    minDate: '+1970/01/02', //tomorrow
    maxDate: '+1970/05/01', //five months ahead
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,      //week begins with monday
    onSelectDate: function(current) {       
        initDaytimePicker(current);
    }
};

function initDaytimePicker(date) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/api',
        data: 'date=' + encodeURIComponent(date),
        success: function(data) {
            datetimepickerOptions.allowTimes = data;            
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#datepicker_input').datetimepicker(datetimepickerOptions);
        }
    });
}

//initialize at page load with todays date
initDaytimePicker(new Date);
```

This works really fine, so I consider it is as solved.